# Delayed Job: process all jobs but from queue X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Is there a way to process all jobs except for jobs from the specified queue? In Delayed Job [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/README.md) I see that I can process all jobs from a named queue like this:

```
# Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start
```

But I want to do something like:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --skip-queue=tracking start
```

Comment: Know it's an old issue, did you ever get a solution to this?